# Using instance as VueJS data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

My question is: Can I use an instance as data in the VueJS?

Take a look at these two ways of update the User's name.

```js
    const vue = new Vue({
        data(){
            return {
                user: {
                    name: 'Denis Wilton',
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
           updateUserName(newName) {
              this.user.name = newName;
           }
        }
    })
```

```
<button @click="updateUserName('Foo Bar')">Change name to Foo Bar</button>
```

In the above way, I can create an event that calls the method "updateUserName('Foo Bar')" passing the newName as param.

Ok! But... What if I create an user instance from the User class, that by yourself carries the method updateName, like this:

```js
//@/classes/User.js
//Class User
class User {
     
     constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
     }

     updateName(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
     }
}


//////////////////////////////

const vue = new Vue({
      data(){
         return {
             user: new User('Denis Wilton'), //Here I instantiated my user class, that owns the 'updateUser' method implicitly.
         }
      }
});
```

In the above example, I can use an event that calls the User's method "updateName" for updating my data, and have no need to code the method at VueJS component's script.

```
<button @click="user.updateName('Foo Bar')">Change name to Foo Bar</button>
```

Am I sinning to do this? LOL

Answer (score 0):

The best response to this was on a reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/gqx58s/anyone_using_oop_principles_in_their_vuejs_spa/

Summary: It might mess with the built in reactivity of vue and give you problems down the line if you use OOP principles in Vue.